# Evaluate the limit using power series without L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits, power-series, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

Show that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x -1}{\sin(x)} = 1$ using power series.

The instructions are not to use L'Hospital's Rule. I cannot find a way to do this without L'Hopital even simplifying using series expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x -1}{\sin(x)} =\lim_{x\to0} \frac{-1+1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...}{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+\frac{x}{2!}+...}{x(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+...} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks! I was over-complicating things. Did not think to pull out x.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution in my opinion using fundamental limits and the definition of the derivative. Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\sin x}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(
\frac{e^x-1}{x}\times \frac{x}{\sin x}
\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\times\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}
=\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)\bigg|_{x=0}\times 1=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

With *high-school limits*:

$$\frac{\mathrm e^x-1}{\sin x}=\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm e^x-1}{x}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\\tfrac{\mathrm{d(e}^x)}{\mathrm dx}\Bigm\vert_{x=0}=1}} \underbrace{\frac x{\sin x}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1}}$$